# How to request data again when I keep alive widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am writing a app with flutter,I set wantKeepAlive to true in page A,and then I request data in initState lifecycle. now, I jump to page B and do something,and then back to page A,I want to request data again because I did something in page B, but the page A is keep alive and it never run initState. so, I should how to request data again?

Comment: you can set a timer to call the method in T seconds or add a button to refresh data manually or even swipe to refresh.

Comment: See `NavigatorObserver`/`RouteObserver`/`RouteAware`

Comment: If I don't do anything in page B, I will not to request data again in page A. so, how to know I did something in page B and then to request data again in page A ?

Comment: I can't request data in build

Comment: You can call the data again once the Navigator pops back to the Page A.

Comment: Are you using `PageView` to show `PageA` and `PageB`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
class PageA extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PageAState createState() => _PageAState();
}

class _PageAState extends State<PageA> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Page A'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('Page A'),
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: goToPageB,
            child: Text('Go to Page B'),
          )
        ],
      )
    );
  }

  void goToPageB(){
    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) {
        return PageB();
      }
    )).then((result){
//      Once you come back from Page B you can
//      fetch your data for page A again here
    });
  }
}

class PageB extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PageBState createState() => _PageBState();
}

class _PageBState extends State<PageB> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Page B'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('Page B'),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
              child: Text('Go to Page A'),
            )
          ],
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! in fact, I jump to many page. I jump to page B from page A and then jump to page C so on...., in last page I update a data, back to page A, I want to know whether has updated data and I need to request data again whether or not. but my request method write in initState in page A, page A is keep alive and initState not run more.

Comment: It seems to me that what you are looking for might be a State Management solution to keep your data up to date in your pages. I would recommend looking up the different options like ScopedModel, BLoC or others available in Flutter. Otherwise you will have to be passing data back and forth between your many pages and eventually it will become hard for you to work.

Comment: I use flutter_redux in my app. it can build widget again when state is changed. I update data by dispach action in page D. page A will rebuild widget but I can't request data in build method,because it will dead cycle.

Comment: Why can't you have the view in Page A getting the data from the Redux store, making it refresh automatically as soon as the data changes?

Comment: Have other way ? the request method is writed in initState in page A. it isn't run by redux dispatch action.

Comment: I'm sorry but that is now very much off the scope of your original question. Please mark this question correct if it answered your original question and ask a new one about redux making requests and keeping data up to date in views from the store. It will be a lot easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

**I got my own solution**

I got four pages and wrap them with pageview widget in another state.

I want to call future with api when another pages value has been changing.

In my case, either my code is don't call initState.

So, I use didUpdateWidget and make wantKeepAlive to look up state widget.

And also I use provider to change value and register global.

I think you can use redux for register value global.

Below is my code. Hope it will be help to you.

**Pageview.dart**

```
   Widget _buildPageView($user) {
    return PageView(
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      controller: _pageController,
      onPageChanged: (index) {
        pageChanged(index);
      },
      children: <Widget>[
        HomePage(pageCtrl:_pageController, keepHeight: $user.userKeepHeight), /// this is the page that I call didUpdateWidget when another value is change. And keepHeight is look up provider value. So, it can be changing dynamically.
        SearchPage(pageCtrl:_pageController),
        ShopPage(),
        MyPage(),
      ],
    );
  }
```

HomePage.dart

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({Key key, this.pageCtrl, this.keepHeight}) : super(key: key);

  final PageController pageCtrl;
  bool keepHeight;

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage>  with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {


  bool _once = true;
  Future _homeFuture;
  final dio = Dio();
  int _totCnt = 0;
  int _listCnt = 0;
  final ScrollController _homeScrollCtrl = new ScrollController();
  bool keepAlive = true;


  var baseUrl = 'https://rest.pickling.kr';
  List<HomeDTO> list1;

  getHomeContentsList(i,j) async {
    Response response;
    try {
      response = await dio.get("$baseUrl/admin/131/home",
          queryParameters: {
            'offset':0,
            'limit': 30
          },
          options: Options(headers: {"Authorization": i, "User-Agent": j}));
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        print(response.data['result']);
        _totCnt = int.parse(response.data['result']['totCnt']);
        _listCnt = int.parse(response.data['result']['listCnt']);
        var les1 = response.data['result']['homeList'];
        list1 = await les1.map<HomeDTO>((json) => HomeDTO.fromJson(json)).toList();

      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    UserState $user = Provider.of<UserState>(context, listen: false);
    QurateState $qurate = Provider.of<QurateState>(context, listen: false);
    if (widget.keepHeight != oldWidget.keepHeight) {
      setState(() {
        keepAlive = widget.keepHeight;
      });

      if(widget.keepHeight == false) {
        setState(() {
          keepAlive = false;
        });
        updateKeepAlive();
        $user.setUserKeepHeight(true);
        _homeFuture = _getHomeFuture($user, $qurate);
      } else {
        setState(() {
          keepAlive = true;
        });
        updateKeepAlive();
      }
    }
  }



  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    UserState $user = Provider.of<UserState>(context, listen: false);
    QurateState $qurate = Provider.of<QurateState>(context, listen: false);
    _homeFuture = _getHomeFuture($user, $qurate);

  }



  _getHomeFuture($user, $qurate) async{
    await getHomeContentsList($user.accessToken, $user.appInfo);
  }

  @override
  // TODO: implement wantKeepAlive
  bool get wantKeepAlive => keepAlive;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
super.build(context);
 return widget code}
```

Summarizing it, When another value is changing, Provider noticed to change value.
That changed value is reactively changing.

And When user reached homepage first time then call initState.
And User reached homepage one more time initState and didUpdateWidget neither them don't called.

But, another value is changed, homepage called didUpdateWidget and called future.

So it can update home page.

Sorry for too long code :X